# InstantCommons doesn't cache - requests files from commons every page load

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm the main developer behind [Practical Plants](http://practicalplants.org). We're using InstantCommons to grab images from the commons, but it seems like they're failing to cache locally, making page loads slow and placing unnecessary burden on the Commons.

I've set `$wgUseInstantCommons=true`, which downloads images just fine, but doesn't cache them. I get this in my debug.log:

```
ForeignAPIRepo: HTTP GET: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?titles=File%3ABrassica_oleracea0.jpg&iiprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment%7Curl%7Csize%7Csha1%7Cmetadata%7Cmime&prop=imageinfo&iimetadataversion=2&format=json&action=query&redirects=true
Class PEAR_Error not found; skipped loading
ForeignAPIRepo: HTTP GET: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?titles=File%3ABrassica_oleracea0.jpg&iiprop=url%7Ctimestamp&iiurlwidth=248&iiurlheight=-1&iiurlparam=248px&prop=imageinfo&format=json&action=query&redirects=true
ForeignAPIRepo::getThumbUrl got remote thumb http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Brassica_oleracea0.jpg/248px-Brassica_oleracea0.jpg
ForeignAPIRepo: HTTP GET: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?titles=mwstore%3A%2F%2Fwikimediacommons-backend%2Fwikimediacommons-thumb%2F1%2F11%2FBrassica_oleracea0.jpg%2F248px-Brassica_oleracea0.jpg&prop=imageinfo&format=json&action=query&redirects=true
ForeignAPIRepo::getThumbUrlFromCache Thumbnail was already downloaded before
ForeignAPIRepo: HTTP GET: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Brassica_oleracea0.jpg/248px-Brassica_oleracea0.jpg
ForeignAPIRepo::getThumbUrlFromCache could not write to thumb path: mwstore://wikimediacommons-backend/wikimediacommons-thumb/1/11/Brassica_oleracea0.jpg/248px-Brassica_oleracea0.jpg
```

Note that the path output in the error `ForeignAPIRepo:getThumbUrlFromCache` was added by me to try and understand the problem a little, so that lines 300-305 in my ForeignAPIRepo.php file look like this

```
$op = array( 'op' => 'create', 'dst' => $localFilename, 'content' => $thumb );
if( !$backend->doOperation( $op )->isOK() ) {
    wfRestoreWarnings();
    wfDebug( __METHOD__ . " could not write to thumb path: ".$localFilename."\n" );
    return $foreignUrl;
}
```

Anyone have a clue what might be going on here? My ./images dir and all subdirectories are 775 (apache user has group rights) so they're definately writable. Furthermore, locally uploaded images work fine.

If I can provide any more information, please let me know!

Comment: I *really* doubt it's going to help, but you could try getting a copy of PEAR_Error installed, to see if anything interesting is reported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to 1.20.2 has fixed this issue, so I'm assuming it was just a bug with the version of MediaWiki I was using (1.19.X).

Answer (score 0):

Note that, starting in MediaWiki 1.27, InstantCommons [will hotlink thumbnails](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/251556/) instead of generating them locally. This will greatly reduce headaches. The configuration can also be used on older releases.